# Surespot versus government surveillance

Tags: instant-messaging

Does anyone know how tight is surespot encryption? .. Does this the government a really hard time decrypting messages or is it simple like they would get it right away. .. Like imagine I was resisting a dictatorial government or something. If it is not what kind of instant messaging services would be good for this purpose.

Comment: We need details on the security architecture. Do you have that info?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to break encryption:

1. Exploit weaknesses in the encryption algorithm to decrypt the message
2. [Ask the encryptor](http://xkcd.com/538/) (e.g. Surespot) to decrypt it for you

According to Surespot, they use [AES 256](https://www.surespot.me/documents/how_surespot_works.html), which, your words, is a really hard encryption to decrypt. So #1 above is covered (if they implemented it correctly!).

But, realistically, governments go straight to #2.